# Insert rows based on text in a cell and the cell below

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a sample Excel report showing sales figures in each office. Column A lists the year, week no., and salesperson. If there are no sales for a particular salesperson that week, that salesperson is not listed for that week - but I need it to be. I would like to run a script to insert a row as a placeholder wherever a salesperson is not listed.

```
   A          | B          | C
              |            |    
2018          | Date1      | Date2
              |            |    
Week 1        |            |
              |            |    
Garcia, J     | 89         | 72
Lesh, P       | 64         | 91
Total         | 153        | 163
              |            |    
Week 2        |            |
              |            |    
Anastasio, T  | 40         | 44
Garcia, J     | 62         | 58
Houser, M     | 28         | 32
Rhoads, R     | 437        | 658
Total         | 657        | 792 
              |            |
```

But I need for all salespersons to be listed. So what I need for it to show is:

```
   A          | B          | C
              |            |
2018          | Date1      | Date2
              |            |    
Week 1        |            |
              |            |    
Anastasio, T  |            |    
Garcia, J     | 89         | 72
Houser, M     |            |    
Lesh, P       | 64         | 91
Rhoads, R     |            |    
Total         | 153        | 163
              |            |    
Week 2        |            |
              |            |    
Anastasio, T  | 40         | 44
Garcia, J     | 62         | 58
Houser, M     | 28         | 32
Lesh, P       |            |    
Rhoads, R     | 437        | 658
Total         | 657        | 792
```

I am new to VBA so I am having trouble finding code to check text in Column A and cell below and if text in Column A is 'Anastasio, T' and text in cell below is 'Garcia, J', do nothing, otherwise insert row below 'Anastasio, T' and enter 'Garcia, J' in cell below 'Anastasio, T'" and continue for each salesperson in the list. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the report already running? Can you please post the code you have already been using? I suspect that you might be able to modify it slightly to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: The report I receive is just a paste values Excel report from our FP&A group. I want to take the report as shown above and create a new report. I don't have any code yet as I'm not sure what code to use. Thank you.

Comment: 1. You get a file listing people with sales. 2. You want a Macro/VBA Script to insert the people that are missing, because they don't have any sales.
This is possible and not too hard, a list of all Salespersons will be needed to compare the list in the file. However, this is not a free coding site, here we will try our best to help you out when you are having issues or you reached a wall with your code. You have reached the wall of not know any VBA. I recommend a beginners VBA guide online. And pardon me if any of this sounds rude, my intention is a wholehearted answer for a future VBA user.

Answer (score 0):

One way of approaching this would be to create your own template report with every salesperson listed, then write a VBA script to:

1. Copy the template to a new sheet
2. Find each salesperson's name in the latest sales report
3. Copy their data across to the new sheet (which will effectively leave a blank row if the person had no sales)

Your first step would be to create the templates then either use the macro recording functionality in Excel, or do some research on 'For Each' and 'If' loops. This should help you get started:

```
Sub salesChecker()

Dim templatePerson As Range
Dim templateSalespeople As Range   ' Set up a range covering all names on the template
Dim reportSalespeople As Range     ' Set up a range covering all names on the report
Dim reportPerson As Range


' Set where these ranges apply
Set templateSalespeople = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A20")  'Example only: you'll need to set ranges
Set reportSalespeople = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A2:A20")    'Example only: you'll need to set ranges


' Loop though each person on the template
For Each templatePerson In templateSalespeople

    ' Check name against each person on the report
    For Each reportPerson In reportSalespeople

        ' If the names match then...
        If reportPerson.Value = templatePerson.Value Then

            ' Copy the value in the cell next to the person's name and paste into template
            reportPerson.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=templatePerson.Offset(0, 1)

        End If

Next

End Sub
```